# Cannot lw the value I want in mips

Tags: integer, mips, cpu-registers

I'm still quite new to MIPS and its commands so I can't seem to find one to suit what I need

So I have an array of values in `$t0` and I need to load the 44th value into a register:

```
lw $t1, 172($t0)
```

My issue is that `172` is worked out before and stored in register `$t2` and it is subject to change. It could be `172`, `168`, `164` or so on.

I know the statement this doesn't work:

```
lw $t1, $t2($t0)
```

Is there a way of using whatever value is in `$t2` as the index for `$t0`?

Comment: add $t1, $t0, $t2 ; lw $t1, 0($t1) would do the job, correct ?

Comment: Great thank you, this works perfectly.